# How to get number of results from a mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I'm doing this query:

```
'SELECT * FROM Album WHERE id = ?;'
```

using a prepare sql statement, and I was wondering how to get the number of results this query returns? B/c since every album id is unique this query should only return 1 album and I want to make sure that its doing that.

### Code

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM Album WHERE id = ?;');
$id = 2;
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$executed = $stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $info['id'] = $row['id'];
    $info['title'] = $row['title'];
    $info['date_created'] = $row['date_created'];
    $info['creator'] = $row['creator'];
}
// Send back the array as json
echo json_encode($info);
```

Comment: If ID is unique then there is only one record. Period. No need to "make sure"

Comment: @juergend it's good to be thorough

Comment: If you would always check if something imposible happened, like 90% of your code would consist such checks.

Comment: @juergend this is not necessarily true: It can be 0 records as well

Comment: @PaulSpiegel This is for debugging purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using `$result->num_rows`:

```
if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $info['id'] = $row['id'];
    $info['title'] = $row['title'];
    $info['date_created'] = $row['date_created'];
    $info['creator'] = $row['creator'];

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    
    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
}
```

You can find more details on [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make sure that its doing that

In your code you are already doing that. The following condition

```
if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

does exactly what you want.

Answer (score -1):

### Just use COUNT(*)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Album WHERE id = ?;
```

Reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

### Another way

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Album WHERE id = ?");
$query->execute();
$count =$query->rowCount();
echo $count;
```

Comment: `rowCount()` is a PDO function.